# DNX Error: Unable to start the process

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I opened up my ASP NET 5 solution today and on load of the project I get the following Microsoft Visual Studio Error. I thought maybe it was an issue with my default runtime but when I run DNVM List everything looks okay.  Any help or direction would be appreciated

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio Error

The following error occurred attempting to run the DNX design time process (dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc2-16357).

Unable to start the process.

The DNX design time process provides intellisense, build, and reference information to Visual Studio and without it your experience will be very limited. Please try closing and reopening Visual Studio to see if that corrects the problem. Alternatively, check that the DNX version is properly installed or try changing to a different installed DNX version using the project property pages.

---

### DNVM List

```
Active Version           Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------------- -----
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x64          win
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          win
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x64          win
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x86          win
       1.0.0-rc2-16177   coreclr x64          win
       1.0.0-rc2-16177   coreclr x86          win
  *    1.0.0-rc2-16357   clr     x86          win             default
       1.0.0-rc2-16357   coreclr x86          win
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I attempted to run a repair on ASP NET 5 and then a repair on Visual Studio 2015 but I still had the error.  I then uninstalled every single runtime in my list, for example

```
dnvm uninstall 1.0.0-rc2-16347 -runtime coreclr
```

After everything was uninstalled, I opened powershell as an administrator and ran

```
dnvm update-self
dnvm upgrade
```

I then reinstalled the runtime and everything was fine again

```
dnvm install 1.0.0-rc2-16357 -runtime coreclr -u
```

Comment: Just the "dnvm upgrade" worked for me. I didn't have the "dnvm uninstall" option. Upvoted anyhoo. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Run  VS: Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console:

- dnvm upgrade
- dnvm upgrade -r CoreClr